# What ways exist to create containers of several types?

Tags: rust, containers

I would like to know the ways to have a container containing several types. I know that:

- A tuple can contain several types
- If I create an enumeration `E`, I can create a `Vec<E>`.

In C++, we can create a `Vec<A*>` containing both `B*` and `C*` elements if `B` and `C` inherit from `A`. Can we do something similar in Rust? For instance, if several types implement the same trait?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You can store references or pointers to trait objects.

2) You can create an enum over the things you want to store.

Comment: I'd definitely +1 if you included working examples.